# リモートサーバアクセスでPostgresqlのバックアップ、リストアを行いたい

Tags: c#, postgresql, database

C#を使用し、リモートサーバーアクセスでPostgresqlのバックアップ、リストアを行いたいのですが、上手くいきません。

前回webシステムを作成した際、pg_dumpを使ってバックアップ、リストアを行ったのですが、その際はファイルをサーバーへ保管し、サーバーからバックアップファイルを取り出しリストアをしました。

しかし今回はクライアントサーバーシステムで、サーバー(Linux)でDBのバックアップを行い、クライアントにそのバックアップファイルを保存したいです。その後、クライアントからバックアップファイルを選択し、リストアを行いたいと思っています。

まず、このようなことは可能なのでしょうか？自分なりに調べてみた結果、ローカルでバックアップ、リストアを行っている例などは多くあったのですが、このようなリモートでバックアップ、リストアを行っている例をあまり見つけられなかったため質問させていただきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

できると思います。
pg_dumpで接続先を指定すれば、サーバで実行するときと同様に、クライアントでもpg_dumpの標準出力をバックアップファイルにリダイレクトできます。
実際に試したわけではありませんが、以下に使い方の説明があります。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/postgresql/howto-migrate-using-dump-and-restore
【注意】SSH接続でサーバにログインし、サーバでpg_dumpを実行するのではなく、クライアント側でpg_dumpを実行するときにサーバのホスト名を指定します。

---

コメントをうけて追記しました。

リストアもクライアント側で実行します。
スクリプト形式でダンプしたのであれば、psqlでローカルのバックアップファイル(クライアント側)を標準出力に読み込ませればリストアできます。
アーカイブ形式でダンプしたのであればpg_restoreにローカルのバックアップファイルを指定すればよいです。

Comment: 提示いただいたサイトのpg_dumpを使用してバックアップを取れることは分かるのですが、クライアントからサーバーへこのコードを投げるとなったときどのような書き方をC#ですればいいのかわかっていない状況です。

Comment: SSH接続でpg_dumpコマンドを打ち込み、結果をクライアント側で保存することは出来たのですが、そのファイルをリストアする方法が分かりません。またSSHを使用してコマンドを打つにしても、どのようにクライアントのファイルをサーバーへ渡せばいいのかが分かりません。

Comment: C#のプログラムからpg_dumpを実行するには、「C# コマンド実行」などで検索すると情報が得られます(https://www.fenet.jp/dotnet/column/language/5722/)。その上でわからないことがあれば、新しく質問した方がよいと思います。

Comment: スクリプト形式でダンプした場合、読み込ませたときにテーブル作成などは上手くいくのですが、COPY句の部分のみどうしてもエラーになっていしまいます。アーカイブ形式でリストアの場合はローカルにバックアップファイルが無ければリストア出来ないのでしょうか？質問文にも記載した通り、クライアントサーバーシステムで、バックアップファイル自体はクライアント側に残したいと考えているのですがそのようなことは出来ないのでしょうか。

Comment: ↑すみません、しっかり編集された回答を見ていませんでした。クライアント側でリストアするので、ローカルはクライアント側のローカルということですね。試して分からないことがあればまた質問させていただきます。

Comment: 「COPY句の部分のみどうしてもエラーになっていしまいます」は実行した内容、エラーの内容がわからないと回答できないと思います。質問の趣旨は「クライアントからリモートで別サーバのデータベースをバックアップしたい」と理解しています。質問に追記するより、別の質問にした方がよいと思います。がんばってください。